# What is the root of magento where I can run code always when magento runs

Tags: frontend, session

I need to run code always when magento starts. Which means any user who visit site must go through this code. Please any one know place to add this code

```
session_start(); 
$cookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];

session_write_close(); 

$ch = curl_init('url_here');
...
...
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
...
... 
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: you can write this code into your applied theme head.phtml file

Comment: Superb. I guessed that. Thank you. Overrided header constructor

Comment: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/32402056167/magento-startup-events

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/choosing-a-right-event-to-observe/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the magento event `controller_action_predispatch` which always get executed. You can bind your code by creating an observer on this event.